# this is a program dealing with canvas and java script

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

bellow is the code from my program that is suppose to lower the blinking ball to the bottom of the screen and stay blinking at the bottom. This process is suppose to take place gradually (incrementing by factor of 10) but it happens suddenly. What should I do?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AnimationDemoCanvas.html &copy; Kari Laitinen</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

var ball_center_point_x = 300 ;
var ball_center_point_y = 240 ;

var current_ball_color = "cyan" ;

var ball_must_be_shown  =  true ;


function draw_on_canvas()
{
   var canvas = document.getElementById( "animation_demo_canvas" ) ;
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d") ;


   context.fillStyle = "rgb( 255, 255, 210 )" ;  
   context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ) ;

   if ( ball_must_be_shown  ==  true )
   {
      context.fillStyle = current_ball_color ; 
      context.beginPath() ;
      ball_center_point_y +=10;
      context.arc(  ball_center_point_x, ball_center_point_y,
                   50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true )

      context.closePath(ball_center_point_y = 429) ;
      context.stroke() ;
      context.fill() ;

      ball_must_be_shown  =  false ;
   }
   else
   {
      ball_must_be_shown  =  true ;
   }


   setTimeout( function () { draw_on_canvas(); }, 100 ) ;
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">

   #centered
   {
      width: 600px;
      height: 500px;
      margin: 30px auto;    

      border: 1px solid black;
   }

</style>
</head>

<body onload="draw_on_canvas()">

   <div id=centered>
      <canvas id=animation_demo_canvas
         width=600 height=500>
      </canvas>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I uploaded the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/5w6GA/2/) for you.

```
var ball_center_point_x = 300 ;
var ball_center_point_y = 240 ;

var current_ball_color = "cyan" ;

var ball_must_be_shown  =  true ;
draw_on_canvas();

function draw_on_canvas()
{
   var canvas = document.getElementById( "animation_demo_canvas" ) ;
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d") ;

   context.fillStyle = "rgb( 255, 255, 210 )" ;  
   context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ) ;
//here is the part in question:

   if ( ball_must_be_shown  ==  true )
   {
      context.fillStyle = current_ball_color ; 
      context.beginPath() ;
      if(ball_center_point_y + 50 < canvas.height)
          ball_center_point_y +=10;
      context.arc(  ball_center_point_x, ball_center_point_y,
                   50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true )

      context.closePath() ;
      context.stroke() ;
      context.fill() ;

      ball_must_be_shown  =  false ;
   }
   else
   {
      ball_must_be_shown  =  true ;
   }


   setTimeout( draw_on_canvas, 100 ) ;
}
```

Basically the problems lies in your setTimeout(), just reference the function itself directly, instead of using string. don't do this `setTimeout("draw_on_canvas()", 100)`

Update:

`if(ball_center_point_y + 50 < canvas.height) 
   ball_center_point_y +=10`;

This portion stops the circle from going through the bottom. Since the diameter dictated in your context.arc() is 50 then add the circle's y-axis(ball_center_point_y), then have it compared against the height of the canvas. if the condition evaluates true then it won't update the y-axis.

Comment: thank you very much but could you explain what this line does:  if(ball_center_point_y + 50 < canvas.height)
          ball_center_point_y +=10;

Comment: what is preventing the ball from passing over the bottom line?

Comment: if(ball_center_point_y + 50 < canvas.height) ball_center_point_y +=10;

prevents the circle from passing over the bottom of the canvas

Answer (score 0):

To make it happen slower, increase the your `setTimeout` value to widen the gap between draw refreshes, perhaps:

```
setTimeout( function () { draw_on_canvas(); }, 300 ) ;
```

Edit: I noticed you don't seem to using setTimeout correctly either.

Comment: edited answer, I didn't initially notice your setTimeout calling a  string instead of a function

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Since there are few corrections I would like to make, I have created an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nd6Xf/

Is this the result that you need?

My remarks are:

1. What is the purpose of `ball_must_be_shown` variable?
2. What is the purpose of an argument `ball_center_point_y = 429` in `closePath()` function?
3. Your `setTimeout()` was wrong.

Also, you will need to adjust the variables (startx, startx, diameter,...) since I lowered them for example script. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: you example has the same problem as mine. the circle has to stay right on the bottom line of the canvas and also be blinking!

Comment: Oh I thought your only problem is the animation going too fast.